# Is it possible to change the text size in the Open and Save dialog boxes?

Tags: macos, finder, text, accessibility

In the Finder, I use the **View Options** to set the text size to **16**.

However, when I **open** and **save** files from within an application, the text size is much smaller.

Is there any way to augment the size of the text in the Open and Save dialogs, **without increasing the size of the menu text etc.**?